# How do I find out what app is generating notification-like sounds on Windows 11

Tags: windows, audio

I am intermittently getting a notification-like sound played on my Windows 11 machine.

I have **Do Not Disturb** enabled on the settings System > Notifications page.   The sounds persist.

I checked the Control panel's sound page, and the sound I'm hearing isn't is not among them.

Is there any tool I can use to find out what program is generating these sounds?

Comment: I have Windows 11 and no unidentified sounds.  Look for Haptics  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/pen-haptics   .   Otherwise looking for a needle in a haystack with SysInternals Process Monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding it by process of elimination.  It turned out to be Visual Studio Code, which made the sound every time I moved the cursor to a line containing an error!   Easy enough to fix once I knew where to look.

Answer (score 1):

first, download process monitor from microsoft and open it. here is the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

second, select filter ---> filter --->
under display entries matching these description choose: Path - contains - .wav
and click on add. the result should be like this
[image]

after you click on it the result will become like this.

[image]

here you can see all processes that are making sounds on your pc

Comment: Good idea; thanks for your participation.

Comment: Well, it isn't coming from a .WAV file...  Good idea, though.